# Activity ActivityMain has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView

Tags: android, dialog

I get this error every time my custom dialogue is shown but I dont understand why.
Here is how i declare my custom dialogue box:

```
  dialogueGettingAllPatients = new DialogueGettingAllPatients(this);
```

Here is how i call the dialogue box and try to update its UI once the tasks is finished:

```
 dialogueGettingAllPatients.show();
        for (ZoneData zone : zonesSelected) {
         ...
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    String rsp = response.body().string();
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonRsp = new JSONArray(rsp);
                        ...
                        dialogueGettingAllPatients.gettingDataSuccess = true;
                        dialogueGettingAllPatients.updateUI();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the code of the dialogue box:

```
   public class DialogueGettingAllPatients extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    private ActivityMain activityMain;
    private ImageView success, failed;
    private Button ok;
    private GifImageView loadingLogo;
    public boolean gettingDataSuccess;


    public DialogueGettingAllPatients(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.activityMain = (ActivityMain) a;
    }

    public void updateUI(){
        if(gettingDataSuccess){
            loadingLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            success.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            failed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialogue_writting_tag);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        success = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageValid);
        failed = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageFailed);
        loadingLogo = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.loadingLogo);

        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_ok:
                dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The full stacktrace:

```
03-21 12:46:30.818 16103-16103/E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: ActivityMain has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{378510be V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-748,264} that was originally added here
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                                at ActivityMain.getPatientsInZones(ActivityMain.java:185)
                                                                                at FragmentNewTrip1.downloadFiles(FragmentNewTrip1.java:225)
                                                                                at FragmentNewTrip1.access$000(FragmentNewTrip1.java:60)
                                                                                at FragmentNewTrip1$2.onClick(FragmentNewTrip1.java:98)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: first of all, please add the error stacktrace, without everything is an asumption. Second, please add the dialog code....

Comment: I added the stacktrace and the full code of the custom dialogue box

Comment: I guess that is not the complete error stacktrace. Most times, this error appears if the dialog code got some error or the activity closes before the dialog has closed. In last case, there could also be an issue on activity code. It´s possible that this is caused by another error, so please check up your error stacktrace if there are some more (disable logcat filter to see all)...

Comment: and updateUI() I guess, must be called in ui thread because you are changing some of it. I guess it must be called inside `runOnUIThread()`